# Error while performing update via String Concat

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am doing a query in which I want to update columns by concate new values to that columns.
I have made a SQL code like below but I am getting an error:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max), @Id INT, @Total_Service_Amount float,
@Total_Cancellation_Charge float, @Total float

SET @Id = 1
SET @Total_Service_Amount = 1
SET @Total_Cancellation_Charge = 2
SET @Total = @Total_Service_Amount + @Total_Cancellation_Charge

SET @sql = 'UPDATE [DBO].[Service_Amount] SET Request_Id = '''
+ CONCAT (Request_Id, CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR), ',') + ''',
Amount = ''' + CONCAT (Amount, CAST(@Total) AS VARCHAR), ',')
+ ''' WHERE Request_For_Id = (SELECT Request_For_Id FROM
[DBO].Request WHERE Id=@Id)' 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I want result like below:
BEFORE:

> **Id | Request_Id    | Amount**
>
> 1  | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 200,300,22,22

AFTER:

> **Id | Request_Id    | Amount**
>
> 1  | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 | 200,300,22,22,12
>
> **Solution:**

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @Id INT, @Total_Service_Amount float, @Total_Cancellation_Charge float, @Total float, @beforeId varchar(500), @beforeAmount varchar(max)
SET @Id = 1
select @Total_Service_Amount = 1
select @Total_Cancellation_Charge = 2
select @Total = @Total_Service_Amount + @Total_Cancellation_Charge


SELECT @beforeId = Request_Id FROM [DBO].[Service_Amount] WHERE Request_For_Id = (SELECT Request_For_Id FROM [DBO].Request WHERE Id= @Id)

SELECT @beforeAmount = Amount FROM [DBO].[Service_Amount] WHERE Request_For_Id = (SELECT Request_For_Id FROM [DBO].Request WHERE Id= @Id)

SET @sql = 'UPDATE [DBO].[Service_Amount] SET Request_Id = ''' + @beforeId + ',' + convert(VARCHAR,@Id) +  ', Amount = ''' + @beforeAmount + ',' + convert(VARCHAR,@Total) + ''' WHERE Request_For_Id = (SELECT Request_For_Id FROM [DBO].Request WHERE Id=' + convert(VARCHAR,@Id) + ')' 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id int', @Id
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JeffRosenberg error at '@sql' that's it.

Comment: How are you executing @SQL? Please post your entire stored procedure / query text.

Comment: Try `select CONCAT('111', '222')` in SSMS, because it doesn't work for me... looks like it's a new feature in MS SQL 2012. Use 'a'+'b'+'c' instead of CONCAT()

Comment: @JeffRosenberg I am executing like: EXEC sp_executesql *@sql*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `@sql = 'UPDATE...` should be `SET @sql = 'UPDATE...`

Also, you need to pass your `@id` parameter into @sql, like so..

`EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id int', @id`

You can read more in the documentation for `sp_executesql`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: I have tried this. But not helping me. I think there is an error in Update statement. But I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Oh, right. You're missing a `SET` command. I edited my answer.

Comment: Tried but now error showing at CONCAT. 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: See @FuzzyButton's comment above: "looks like it's a new feature in MS SQL 2012. Use 'a'+'b'+'c' instead of CONCAT()"

Comment: Can I get old column in that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean column value before I am updating it. Like if before value is 1,2,3 after value is 1,2,3,4. I want this.

Comment: If you can get it using the `CONCAT()` function, it will be exactly the same using `+`. The code is just a little more cluttered.

Comment: You've combined my and @Scorpi0's advice regarding the handling of `@id` -- pick one, since they're mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to glue together a load of fields from a SELECT query, into one string, have a play with this kind of thing :

```
select STUFF(
               (SELECT ',',  Request_Id as [text()]
                FROM [DBO].[Service_Amount]
                FOR XML PATH ('')
               )
             , 1, 1, '')
```

This can be set into a variable
`Set @my_var = (SELECT Stuff... )`
and used in the `UPDATE` sql

The `FOR XML` part does the gluing together, the `STUFF` just removes the leading comma.

Comment: Do you actually want to add a new value onto a previously correct value (a very simple UPDATE) or do you need to build the string value from scratch each time? (which probably calls for the `FOR XML` approach outlined in my answer)